# own iterator class not working with std::binary_search

Tags: c++, iterator

I found a lot of answers here to the topic, but I couldn't get my code to run.

**EDIT:**
The posted example now works after introducing the missing things. In hope some one can use the example as basis for own experiments. I also introduced the missing things to use this example as random access iterator. It works much more efficient with binary_search algos.

If I have to write my own iterator I struggle with value_type and other "specials" to operate with .

I read a lot of articles here how to NOT write iterators but could not get any working example. Especially I read that I should not derive from iterator. So I will ask stupid again:

How can I define the value_type of my iterator. It did not work with in class definition and also did not work with defining manually over type_traits struct. No idea how to continue...

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <algorithm>
     #include <type_traits>
     #include <iterator>

    using namespace std;

    int data[]= { 1,4,7,9,11,20,28 }; //Sorted data

    template < typename T >
    class MyIter
    {
        int offset;
        T* base;

        public:
        typedef int value_type;

        //add the following lines after reading the answers -> it works! 
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T * pointer;
        typedef T & reference;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

        // if you want to use as random access iterator:
        // typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

        public:
        MyIter( T* _base, int _offset) : base(_base), offset(_offset) {}
        MyIter() {}

        bool operator !=( const MyIter& rhs) 
        {
            T* tmp1= base+offset;
            T* tmp2= rhs.base + rhs.offset;

            return tmp1 != tmp2;
        } 

        MyIter operator++(int)
        {
            MyIter tmp(*this);
            offset++;
            return tmp;
        }

        T operator*()
        {
            return *(base+offset);
        }

        // Addition: if used as random access iterator you must provide:
        int operator-(const MyIter& rhs)
        {
            return offset-rhs.offset;
        }

        MyIter operator+=(int off)
        {
            offset+=off;
            return *this;
        }


    };

    typedef MyIter<int> iterType ;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "ok" << endl;

        pair<iterType, iterType> bounds;

        MyIter<int> start( data,0);
        MyIter<int> ende ( data,7);

        bounds = equal_range( start, ende, 28 );

        for ( iterType it= bounds.first; it!=bounds.second; it++)
        {
            cout << "Found " << *it << endl;
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: _How_ does it not work? Compilation errors? Runtime errors? Not behaving as expected? Something else?

Comment: where did you read not to derive from `std::iterator`?

Comment: @rhalbersma I missed that one.  I think some early C++ compilers didn't propagate typedef in a base class correctly, so deriving from `std::iterator` didn't work, but that hasn't been a problem for years.  (Those compilers also had a lot of other problems with the standard library, and shouldn't be in use today.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah nice to know. That sounds similar to the workarounds for the old specialize swap in namespace std stuff that used to be done for compilers that didn't properly implement ADL.

Comment: @rhalbersma Yes.  But notice that I'm talking about compilers that are 15 or more years old (and don't fully implement C++98).  The _only_ thing to do in such cases is upgrade the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a few definitions in addition to `value_type` that the standard library requires from iterators:

```
typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef T * pointer;
typedef T & reference;
typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
```

Alternatively, inheriting from `std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>` will give you these. I don't know where you read that you shouldn't do that, but that's exactly what `std::iterator` is for.

Additionally, you're missing a pre-increment operator:

```
MyIter operator++()
{
    ++offset;
    return *this;
}
```

and also `->` and `==` operators. Also, the dereference operator should probably return a reference to allow `*it = 42`, with a `const` overload returning a value or `const` reference.

Comment: Thanks! My first try results in `no type named »value_type« in »struct std::iterator_traits<MyIter<int>`, so I did not work on the other attributes. By adding the other attributes the missing value_type error is gone!? I do not understand why! Any explanation for that mystery ?

Comment: @Klaus: I've no idea. I certainly get an error if I don't either define `value_type` or inherit from `std::iterator`. However, there's no guarantee that you'll get an error if they're missing, unless your code instantiates some template that needs them.

Answer (score 1):

`std::binary_search` requires a random access iterator.  Which
means that the iterator must support addition and subtraction
(`+`, `+=`, `-` and `-=`), with exactly the same semantics as
a pointer.  And any number of algorithms will also expect
a number of typedef in the iterator: deriving from
`std::iterator` is the easiest way to get them.  (Technically,
what the standard requires is that `std::iterator_traits` yield
the correct values, so you could explicitly instantiate it for
your iterator.  But its default implementation picks up typedef
in the iterator class.)

### EDIT:

Rereading your post: you definitly *should* publically derive from `std::iterator`.  Whoever says otherwise is wrong.

Comment: No, `binary_search` only requires a forward iterator. It won't be very efficient without random access, but that isn't a requirement.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The number of comparisons for `binary_search` with ForwardIterator is still `O(log N)`, but RandAccessIterators are more efficient because they don't have to do so many increments (the difference is in `std::advance`)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Really.  I didn't know that.  (It would never have occured to me to even try it with less than random access.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Binary search on a sorted `std::forward_list` comes to mind?

Comment: @Klaus: See tables 110 and 111 in the C++11 standard. Basically, you need both forms of `--` to make it bidirectional; and `+`, `+=`, `-`, `-=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` and `[]` to make it random-access; and you'd tag it with `std::random_access_iterator_tag`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks, in the same moment you post your comment I deleted mine :-) I got it to work and after having an basic idea it is really simple. Thanks for breaking the wall in my head!

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes.  I forgot the comparison operators (To me, `--` seems to be implied by subtraction, but since I was listing the operators.)  With regards to the tag, that's handled by `std::iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing several essential type members and the pre-increment operator (as well as a bunch of other dereference and comparison operators as pointed out by @MikeSeymour). Add thise to your class definition (note that I rewrote the post-increment operators in terms of the currently missing pre-increment operator) to get your `binary_search` going

```
typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef T* pointer;
typedef T& reference;

MyIter& operator++()
{
    ++offset;
    return *this;                      
}

MyIter operator++(int)
{
    MyIter tmp(*this);
    ++*this; // NOTE this will call the other operator++
    return tmp;
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ureGM%2417) As pointed out by @JamesKanze, these missing typedefs are provided by inheriting from `std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>`.